# Dataflow is reprocessing input file through entire pipeline from the beginning

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The title of this question is just my hypothesis and I would like you to ask about it.

I have dataflow pipeline (Python) which does something like this:

1. Put file in GCS bucket.
2. GCS bucket sends notification to PubSub topic.
3. PubSub topic triggers Dataflow streaming pipeline.
4. Some DoFn transformations.
5. Write to BigQuery.

I discovered that one file that had been processing didn't land in BQ table.
No errors, all logs showed that all is fine and we came to the final step - write to BQ.
After several seconds the same file started to be processed again, from the beginning.

Have you seen this mechanism in your pipelines?
I have two theories:

1. GCS send's duplicated notifications and that's why process for one file was triggered twice. This makes sense, also this is described in google documentation but this not explains why first pipeline run didn't succeed (I could not find this file in BQ target table).
2. WriteToBiqQuery step failed (silently) and dataflow/apache beam decided to reprocess the file from the beginning. That would make sense but I can't find any prove that this mechanism is a real thing.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Reading from PubSub may cause duplication in your pipeline. You should use `id_label` for deplucation [see docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.io.external.gcp.pubsub.html?highlight=readfrompubsub#apache_beam.io.external.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub). But as you have mentioned in your first theory - this does not explain why it didn't show up in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think when the file is added in the `Cloud storage` bucket, two events are fired.

In order to be sure to treat your file when he has finished to be added to the bucket, you need to add a filter on your `Dataflow` job on `event type` with `OBJECT_FINALIZE` value.

You can check the documentation for GCS to Pub Sub events and notifications :

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it is already set as OBJECT_FINALIZE only, so I assume that one event is fired only